# Highlighting date with event in datepicker from mysql database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, jquery-ui

Trying to make dates from my database to be "highlighted" in the datepicker using jquery and php. I have looked everywere to find something to help me...

This is the code I am using at the moment.
Notice that it has a onSelect state that makes it possible to click on a date and get an event from the database and print it to a div, this works and now i want to make the dates with events highlighted too..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var SelectedDates = {};
        $.getScript('eventdates.php', function(eventsdate) {
            eventsdate;
        });
        $("#kalender").datepicker({
            firstDay: 1,
            dayNamesMin: ['Sö', 'Må', 'Ti', 'On', 'To', 'Fr', 'Lö'],
            monthNames: ['Januari', 'Februari', 'Mars', 'April', 'Maj', 'Juni', 'Juli', 'Augusti', 'September', 'Oktober', 'November', 'December'],
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
            beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                var Highlight = SelectedDates[date];
                if (Highlight) {
                    return [true, "Highlighted", Highlight];
                }
                else {
                    return [true, '', ''];
                }
            },
            onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
                var myDate = new Date(dateText);
                var newFormat = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', myDate);
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'events.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {selectedData: newFormat},
                    success: function(result) {
                        if (result.date === newFormat) {
                            $('#event').html(result['date'] + " " + result['event']);
                        }
                        else {
                            $('#event').html(result['none']);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    });​
```

eventdates.php

```
<?php

include_once ('connect.php');
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `events`");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    echo "SelectedDates[new Date('{$row['date']}')] = new Date('{$row['date']}')<br/>";
}
?>
```

events.php

```
<?php
include_once ('connect.php');
if (isset($_POST['selectedData'])) {
    $sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `events` WHERE `date`='{$_POST['selectedData']}'");
    $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql2);
    if ($row2['date'] == $_POST['selectedData']) {
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `events` WHERE `date`='{$_POST['selectedData']}'");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
            $data = array(
                "date" => $row['date'],
                "event" => utf8_encode($row['event'])
            );
            echo json_encode($data);
        }
    } else {
        $data = array(
            "none" => "Inget event denna dag!"
        );
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem and wanted to share my solution with everyone else that struggles with this kind och problem!

jQuery script

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#kalender").datepicker({
            firstDay: 1,
            dayNamesMin: ['Sö', 'Må', 'Ti', 'On', 'To', 'Fr', 'Lö'],
            monthNames: ['Januari', 'Februari', 'Mars', 'April', 'Maj', 'Juni', 'Juli', 'Augusti', 'September', 'Oktober', 'November', 'December'],
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
            onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
                var myDate = new Date(dateText);
                var newFormat = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', myDate);
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'events.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {selectedData: newFormat},
                    success: function(result) {
                        if (result.date === newFormat) {
                            $('#event').html(result['date'] + "<br />\n" + result['event']);
                        }
                        else {
                            $('#event').html(result['none']);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }, beforeShowDay: function(date) {

                var yy = date.getFullYear(), mm = date.getMonth() + 1, dd = date.getDate();
                if (dd < 10) {
                    var dt = yy + "-" + mm + "-0" + dd;
                } else {
                    var dt = yy + "-" + mm + "-" + dd;
                }
<?php include_once ('eventdates.php') ?>
                return [true, ''];

            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

events.php

```
<?php
include_once ('connect.php');
if (isset($_POST['selectedData'])) {
    $sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `events` WHERE `date`='{$_POST['selectedData']}'");
    $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql2);
    if ($row2['date'] == $_POST['selectedData']) {
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `events` WHERE `date`='{$_POST['selectedData']}'");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
            $data = array(
                "date" => $row['date'],
                "event" => utf8_encode($row['event'])
            );
            echo json_encode($data);
        }
    } else {
        $data = array(
            "none" => "Inget event denna dag!"
        );
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
}

?>
```

eventdates.php

```
<?php

include_once ('connect.php');
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `events`");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    echo "var selDate" . $row['event_ID'] . " = '" . $row['date'] . "';";
    echo "if (dt === selDate" . $row['event_ID'] . ") {";
    echo "return [true, 'Highlighted'];";
    echo "}";
}
?>
```

Hope this helps someone else!

Comment: Is there a chance you still have this script up and running?

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is asynchronous by definition. This means you are running the datepicker code before `$.geScript` has been completed. You need to call the datepicker code in the callback of `$.getScript`

```
$.getScript('eventdates.php', function() {
         /* new script has fired*/
         $("#kalender").datepicker({.....});

});
```

Comment: this makes the whole datepicker to crash, any suggestions?

Comment: I havent figured out how to display errors in jQuery just yet...
But when I see this solution it doesn't make sense to me. The eventdates.ph file contains only a list of dates that is supposed to display in the code. The dates are generated from a SQL database.
I don't know if this methos works. I need help to make it work, not that way maybe but somehow.

Comment: use a browser console to look for errors.. Firebug in Firefox, or hit F12 key in Chrome. This is an absolute first step always in debugging any javascript

Comment: should work, also I tested returning a js variable from php page using `$.getScript` and worked fine. Hard to troubleshoot without seeing full code you have implemented. One thing to check is look at ajax request in console and see what is in the data returend from `eventdates.php`. Also inside $.getScript` callback can call `console.log(SelectedDates)` and look in console to see that object is valid

Comment: `console.log(eventsdate)` printed the right thing but `console.log(SelectedDates)` didnt print out anything in console.

Comment: remove both references of `eventsdate` shouldn't need it. The script you receive is updating `SelectedDates` object. Also check what is actually sent from php in console inspection of request. Look in `Net` tab

Comment: Now it prints out the right code from the document with `console.log(SelectedDates)` but the datepicker still doesn't show.

Comment: suspect it could be `var Highlight = SelectedDates[date];` maybe format is incorrect. log `Highlight` and see what it is

Comment: It doesn't output anything with `console.log(Highlight)`

Comment: there has to be an error thrown somehwere for datepicker not to work, or selector is wrong or something. `console.log(Highlight) ` should only log when you select a date. Add more to log to make sure it is logging at all like ``console.log('this text will always show in console',Highlight) `

Comment: Is the array even properly done like this?
`SelectedDates[new Date('2012-11-22')] = new Date('2012-11-22');`

Comment: `this text will always show in console undefined` is what i get now. I think its the array that isnt read properly

Comment: actually no...format of `object[object]` won't work. Better: `SelectedDates[(new Date('2012-11-22')).getTime()] ` and convert the datpicker dat object with `getTime` also. Will look like `SelectedDates[1353542400000]=....`

Comment: here:  `var Highlight = SelectedDates[date];`  `date` is  javscript date object that needs to be converted

Comment: Maybe im stupid but I don't understand... I need to convert the date format `2012-11-22` with `.getTime()` and it becomes `1353542400000`, that works and `console.log(SelectedDates)` prints those numbers.
Then what, and how do I code it?

Comment: you need the same format for the version of `date` in `var Highlight = SelectedDates[date];` as you use to create  `SelectedDates[date]=new Date()`